# How can I force an XSLT result tree to serialize with a particular default namespace?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to strip the namespace qualifiers from a document, while retaining the document namespace as the default:

```
<foo:doc xmlns:foo='somenamespace'>
    <foo:bar />
</foo:doc>
```

To

```
<doc xmlns='somenamespace'>
    <bar/>
</doc>
```

(I know, this is meaningless, but our client doesn't get XML and uses string comparisons to find information in the document.)

I'm using Java's JAXP Transformer API to do my work here.  I can strip out *all* namespace information with this stylesheet, but I want instead to force serialization without prefixes:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
    <xsl:stylesheet 
          xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'  
          xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
          exclude-result-prefixes='xs' 
          version='2.0'> 

      <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes' indent='yes'/>

      <xsl:template match='@*|node()'> 
        <xsl:copy> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()' /> 
        </xsl:copy> 
      </xsl:template> 

      <xsl:template match='*'> 
        <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'> 
          <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()' /> 
        </xsl:element> 
      </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is there any chance you can help your client properly handle XML? Perhaps you can write a library they can use? I don't think you're doing them any favors by allowing them to continue thinking this is what XML is about. Among other things, next thing you know, they'll be asking me to do the same thing! Where do our standard go when we allow our customers to violate them?

Comment: Oh, christ, I _wish_.

No.

And yes, I'm aware that I'm not doing them any favours.  It also doesn't matter.  If I could have changed their usage, I would not have specifically stated that my requirements are illogical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the output to retain the "somenamespace" namespace, but not have a namespace prefix on the elements, declare "somenamenamespace" in the unnamed namespace (without a prefix) in your stylesheet:  **xmlns='somenamespace'**

Then the elements created using the local-name() will have that namespace, but will not have a namespace prefix:

```
<doc xmlns="somenamespace">
    <bar/>
</doc>
```

Are you seeing warnings when you execute your stylesheet about ambiguous rule matches?
The template match for "node()" and "*" both trigger a match on an element.

**node()** is a shortcut for specifying: "*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()"

You should do one of two things to resolve the ambiguous match:

1.) Change the template match for "@*|node()" to exclude elements by explicitly matching the other node types.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'  
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
    xmlns='somenamespace'
    exclude-result-prefixes='xs' 
    version='2.0'> 

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes' indent='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match='@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()'> 
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()' /> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match='*' > 
        <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()' /> 
        </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2.) Add the priority attribute to the template match for "*", which bumps up the priority match and ensures that it gets called in favor of the "@*|node()".

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'  
    xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    xmlns='somenamespace' 
    exclude-result-prefixes='xs' 
    version='2.0'> 

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration='yes' indent='yes'/>

    <xsl:template match='@*|node()'> 
        <xsl:copy> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()' /> 
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match='*' priority="1"> 
        <xsl:element name='{local-name()}'> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()' /> 
        </xsl:element> 
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't what you want a template matching "`sn:*`" instead of "`*`" and having a

```
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="sn" result-prefix="#default"/>
```

in addition? (provided you have xslns:sn="somenamespace")